# Legacy component + jquery + SEO = 404

Tags: joomla-4.x, jquery, seo

I have a **legacy** joomla 4 component that saves something back to the server using jquery. It works fine with SEO turned off, but I get a 404 error with SEO turned on. The URL parameter for the jquery is

```
index.php?option=com_todomanager&task=save&format=raw
```

Everything else works fine with SEO turned on.

Am I just looking for a rewrite rule that just keeps this URL as is rather than trying to make it search engine friendly?

Answer (score 3):

I needed a / in front of the jquery url:

/index.php?option=com_todomanager&task=save&format=raw

Otherwise the url would get prepended with a menu item path, which was causing the 404

tasks/index.php?option=com_todomanager&task=save&format=raw